# Not able to access echarts instance in echarts for react

Tags: reactjs, echarts

Wanted to clear brush using dispatchAction API of eChartsInstance. But not able to access echarts instance.

```
<ReactEcharts ref={(e) => { this.echarts_react = e; }}
  option={this.getOption()} />
```

Error: Property 'echarts_react' does not exist on type 'className'.

Comment: Anyone , please share me working example of echarts instance for react

Comment: 'getEchartsInstance' does not exist on type 'ReactEcharts'. I get this error if I try to set createref with ReactEcharts type

Comment: Can you share the piece of code where you are calling the `getEchartsInstance` method?